# Setting up VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, mount, lvm

I just recently reformatted my hard drive to multiboot 3 different linux distros.  I installed Kali first, and used the installer to create logical volumes where I later installed CentOS and Ubuntu.  I installed Ubuntu to mount the root directory in a 20GB lvm, and then mounted the home directory in a separate 10GB lvm.  I also created a separate 300GB lvm that I labeled "VMfiles" with the intention of installing VirtualBox on the Ubuntu host and then installing a VM for Ubuntu, Windows 8, Kali, and CentOS, and the plan is to place the VM files on the VMfiles lvm.  I decided to use the Ubuntu installer to mount the VMfiles lvm in Ubuntu's home directory.

The problem is when I go into VirtualBox and try to create a 25GB VM in the /home/VMfiles directory, I get an error that creating the VM file would overwrite the size of the directory.  I know my /home is only 10GB, but if /home/VMfiles is just a mount point for a 300GB lvm, why is that 300GB not available?

Comment: The default location for new VM's is `/home/username/VirtualBox VMs` - what I do is symlink that directory to my large partition (well, RAID-1) located at `/storage`

Comment: Thanks.  It seemed that going into the VirtualBox preferences and changing the location for the VirtualBox VM's to the directory I mounted my lvm reserved for VM's did the trick.  I also logged out and logged back in, not sure if it had something to do with resetting environmental variables or something.

Comment: Cool. Don't forget that those settings (as well as what machines exist, etc) are kept in `~/.config/VirtualBox`  or `~/.VirtualBox`